# Ajax call failing to post data on "success"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a simple AJAX function below that onclicking a button #submit_message which is on a modal, data is sent to a page (insert_message.php) where the data is entered into a database and the modal reloads. I want to send the value of id which is recipient_id to the modal. The first part of the function works and the modal loads perfectly, but the post data to the modal is not being posted - as in nothing - on Firebug the data is posted to insert_message.php, but on return nothing. I have very similar functions that do other things and these work fine. I have searched for an answer but I think this is a very specific problem, so no success. It may even be a syntax issue - I am new to jQuery.

```
$("#submit_message").click(function(){
   var recipientId = $('#profile_id').val();
   var subject = $('#message_subject').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '../ajax/insert_message.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          'subject': $('#message_subject').val(),
          'message': $('#message_field').val(),
          'recipientId': recipientId,
          },
            success: function(html) {
               $('.message_holder').load('message_modal.php', {id: recipientId});
               $('input[type="text"],text').val('');
               $('input[type="text"],textarea').val('');
              }
            });
       return false;
      });
```

Here is the PHP file....

```
 if(isset($_POST['subject']) 
  && !empty($_POST['subject'])                
  && isset($_POST['message']) 
  && !empty($_POST['message'])
  && isset($_POST['recipientId'])
  && !empty($_POST['recipientId'])){

  $message = new Message();
  $message->subject = ($_POST['subject']);
  $message->message = ($_POST['message']);
  $message->time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time());
  $message->sender_id = $_SESSION['sender_id'];
  $message->recipient_id = $_POST['recipientId'];
  $message->status = "unread";
  $message->create();
}
```

The PHP file works, and the data being sent to it gets to the database...so this is running fine. Still testing other areas. I have this odd feeling its nothing to so with the jQuery and more to do with the Modal....lacking inclusion of a needed file or something. Working on it now.....(ps i have the isset and !empty statements because I find occasional unexpected behaviours with PHP in this regard.....)

Here is the output - parameters get sent and inserted into database.....

```
      Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
      message           Message
      recipientId   162
      subject           Subject

       Source
       subject=Subject+&message=Message+&recipientId=162
```

Then the console log says.....

```
      (nothing to output)  scripts_ajax.js (line 66)
```

No errors reported......still working on it....thanks for your attention,

Bit of a mess posting the full form here, but this is the message_modal.php looks like. I am thinking at this stage the problem is here.....

```
 <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal-mail">
    <p>Message to <?php echo User::full_name($id);?><p>


    <?php 

        if(isset($_POST['recipientId'])){
            //DO STUFF 
            }
    ?>
             <form action="" method="post">
                  <table>   
                        <tr> 
                            <td>  
                            <input id="message_subject" name="subject" type="text" 
                            placeholder="Message subject" size="20"  maxlength="3000" value=""/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                        
                  </table>
                  <table>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>        
                            <textarea id="message_field" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Message details"></textarea>                               
                            </td>
                        </tr>      
                  </table>
                <input id="submit_message" type="button" name="submit" value="submit" />                
                <input id="profile_id" type="hidden" name="submit" value="<?php echo $id;?>"/>           
           </form>
 <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
```

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with this code. See if this code is being executed, and that it reaches the `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: If insert_message.php isn't returning anything, your first debugging step is to ensure the php is working correctly.  Post that instead, or at least confirm it works.

Comment: Several suggestions.  1) Put a `console.log()` statement or breakpoint in your `success` handler to see if it's getting called.  2) If it's not getting called, then define an `error` handler for the ajax call and log the arguments to that to see why it's returning an error and 3) Look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger to see exactly what is coming back from your server to your client. 4) Check the debug console to see if any errors are being reported.

Comment: try this way for ajax call debuging success:funcition(response,textStatus,jqXHR){console.log(response);},error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){console.log(textStatus);
}

Comment: What about the message_modal.php file - what does that look like?  Also, the $('input[type="text"],text').val('') and $('input[type="text"],textarea').val('') selectors are likely firing before your .load command finishes.  Use a complete function with your .load.  See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and its nothing unexpected or untoward.

The class 'message_holder' referred to in the ajax function was mispelt on the HTML page.

Retarded error.

Apologies for wasting peoples time